# AA versus AA what is the chance of winning

Tags: probability

AA versus AA the only way to win or lose is a flush

What is the chance of a flush?

To me a general answer on how to calculate odds is not a duplicate.  I think most or many people on this site would not know how to calculate this situation even with those instructions.  I may open a meta.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate poker hand probabilities?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-calculate-poker-hand-probabilities)

Comment: Keep in mind that a straight flush will also win for only one hand.

Comment: Wouldn't it be lower since I thought even the probability of each person even being dealt AA is .45%. Just lost AA vs AA so I looked this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running [AA vs AA in ProPokerTools](http://www.propokertools.com/simulations/show?g=he&h1=AA&h2=AA&s=generic) gives us an approximate 2.2% probability of winning, presuming it's an all-in preflop situation.

Comment: I get 2.22 from that link.  Don't know why my answer is different.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake. It's 2.2%.

Comment: I get 2.17 with Equilab

Comment: I rounded up, it was 2.17 something.

Answer (score 0):

Using [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

(combin(12,4)*2*36 + combin(12,5)) / combin(48,5) = 0.0217 = 1 / 42

More often than I would have guesed

Comment: COULD YOU REPHARSE THIS QUESTION ONE OF THE USERS FLAGGED THE QUWSTION AS CONFUSING