# What are the odds in five card draw

Tags: probability, 5-card-draw

We play generally five card draw poker with friends at home and we play with 32 cards, not 52.

Could someone show me the way of calculating my drawing odds?

Comment: You need to be a little more specific about what you're asking here - what odds are you trying to calculate exactly? There is a reasonably good answer [here](https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/8078/4771) which gives an intro to probability math for poker which you might also find helpful.

Comment: The number of cards in a deck only effects the numbers used for calculating odds, not how to calculate them.

Comment: did you lose some of the cards? ;-D

Answer (score 0):

If you have one out its at a base level, 1/32 which is approx. 3.125 %.

This doesn't factor in discounted outs or redistribution of discarded cards, as I'm assuming this happens with a 32 Card deck and playing 5 card draw. As your blind to this, it would be very difficult to do. If you're playing single or triple draw this would vary the odds also.

Answer (score 0):

Can only assume you are playing with 8 of each suite.

Now it is harder to make a straight and flush so order of the hand need to be reevaluate.

```
straight = 4 * 5^4 / combin(32,5)       = 0.0031036469  

flush = 4 * combin(8, 5) / combin(32,5) = 0.0013904338 

full house  13 * combin(8, 3) * 12 * combin(8, 2) / combin(32,5) = 0.0185920864
```